# interrogative and affirmative sentence constructions

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, questions

Say we have the following sentence : `The further information I need is to know in which building is the class held.` Is it grammatically correct to place `is` where it's placed in the sentence, or should it be moved after the word `class`, like this: `...in which building the class is held.` The sentence isn't interrogative, so my guess is the second variant is fine, but I'm not sure of the first one.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I didn't write it, this is an extraction from a longer text created by a non-native speaker , that is, an average English learner. It's just that specific word-order mentioned in the question I'm interested in.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I didn't post the question to discuss whether the word order is poor and even horrible or not. The only thing I'm concerned about is the correct placing of "is".

Comment: _in which building the class is held_ sounds to me as good as it's going to get.

Comment: More informal but ok-sounding to me, with rather fewer words, is "I also need to know which building the class is in".

Comment: It’s clear both that you did post the question to discuss the word order, as in *Is it grammatically correct to place is where it's placed…* and that this belongs in English Language Learners https://ell.stackexchange.com

Your problems all lie in what you seem to think of as the irrelevant part: *The… information… is …*. That *is* is in the wrong place.

*The… information… is … in which building is the class held* works.

*The… information… is … in which building is the class held* works.

*The… information… is … which building holds/held the class* works.

Answer (score 0):

To a native speaker, the wording sounds kind of awkward.

One non-interrogative suggestion that retains the meaning is:

> The additional information I need to know is which building the class is held.

Comment: To a native speaker, your suggestion sounds ungrammatical.

Comment: The quoted sentence isn't flawless, I know, and I've no idea who's the author. I'm just curious which of my two versions is correct, and which is not, and why.

Comment: @user74749 Ah I see. The first version "The further information I need is to know in which building is the class held" is not correct because the "further information" is not "to know..."
The second version "The further information I need to know in which building the class is held" is not correct because the "further information" is not referring to anything at all.

Comment: @Sritej Attaluri Those aren't the mistakes I referred in the question. I put the emphasis on a different aspect at all. Where should "is" be placed, and why. It's just a bad example of a broader subject, just think of a sentence structure similar to this.